# Outlet not rendering a path on react router v6

Tags: reactjs

I am making routes that redirect base on if the user is logged in or not.
Basically, if the user is logged in on the sign-in page it should redirect him to the dashboard and vice versa as well as '/'.

The issue in the following code is that going to '/' renders nothing.

Here is the code app.js
`function App() {

```
function App() {

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<PrivateRoute />}>
          <Route path='/Dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='/Sign-in' element={<LoginSignup />} />
        <Route path='/Dashboard' element={<PrivateRoute />}>
          <Route path='/Dashboard' element={<Dashboard />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

And here is my private route function:

```
const PrivateRoute = () => {
    const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const checkAuthentication = async () => {
            const authenticated = await isUserAuthenticated();
            setIsLoggedIn(authenticated);
            setIsLoading(false);
        };

        checkAuthentication();
    }, []);

    if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <div>Loading...</div>
        );
    }

    return isLoggedIn ? (
        <Outlet />
    ) : (
        <Navigate to="/sign-in" />
    );
};
```

I tried doing all sort of private routes but none of them are working, this one seems to be the closest I can get without any sort of issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you dont have home route

```
return (
 <Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<PrivateRoute />}>
      <Route path='/' element={<Dashboard />} /> // here you need to add the home route
    </Route>
```

The idea behind it is you are saying in the parent route if i visit `"/"` then load the `PrivateRoute` then if the `PrivateRoute` is `true` ( return the `Outlet` ) then the router can see the children but your child has the route `/Dashboard`.

Here is an example i did in the new router setup

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const PrivateRoute = () => {
  const hasLocalToken = !!localStorage.getItem("token");

  return hasLocalToken ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
};
export default PrivateRoute;

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <PrivateRoute />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Layout />,
        children: [
          { path: "/", element: <Home /> },
          { path: "/users", element: <Users /> },
          { path: "/notifications", element: <Home /> },
          { path: "/devices", element: <Users /> },
        ],
      },
    ],
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
  },
  { path: "/login", element: <Login /> },

]);
```

Here is the layout to see how i used `Outlet` twice

```
const Layout = () => {
  const [isSidebarCollapsed, setIsSidebarCollapsed] = useState(true);

  const handleIsSidebarOpen = () => {
    setIsSidebarCollapsed((prev) => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <Flex justify="center" align="center">
      <Space direction="vertical" className={styles.mainContainer}>
        <AntLayout className="fullHeight">
          <Navbar
            onSidebarOpenChange={handleIsSidebarOpen}
            isSidebarCollapsed={isSidebarCollapsed}
          />
          <AntLayout>
            <AntLayout>
              <Content />
            </AntLayout>
            <Sidebar isCollapsed={isSidebarCollapsed} />
          </AntLayout>
          <Footer />
        </AntLayout>
      </Space>
    </Flex>
  );
};
```

And here deep down where i use it

```
const Content = () => {
  return (
    <AntContent>
      <Outlet />
    </AntContent>
  );
};
```